# Converting kB and GB to MB in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Im using awk and sed to get a list of partitions in table with their size, which I want to use to calculate the daily increment for individual tables. This is the output I have, now Im struggling to convert all of the sizes to MBs.

What would be the best bash way to match the number in the second field and multiply it depending on the "MB" or "GB" string

```
2017061505,482.46MB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061505,
2017061505,722.58MB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061506,
2017061507,1.03GB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061507,
2017061507,1.25GB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061508,
```

The desired output would be:

```
2017061505,482.46MB,hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061505,
2017061506,722.58MB,hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061506,
2017061507,1030MB,hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061507,
2017061508,1250MB,hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061508,
```

Comment: Is there no alternative way to generate the output?

Comment: ok, post the expected output

Comment: @user37421 Its the output of "show partitions" query in Impala, however I can probably format it better. I was thinking that in the end I would just sum the second field for each table and get the result

Comment: @k_mishap if you just want the sum in megabytes, you can use bc?

`awk -F, '{sub("MB", "", $2) || sub("kB", "/1024", $2) || sub("GB", "*1024", $2); printf $2 "+"} END {print 0}' $The_File | bc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ s=substr($2,1,length($2)-1); u=substr($2,length($2)-1); 
     if(u=="KB") $2=(s/1024)"MB"; else if(u=="GB") $2=(s*1024)"MB" }1' yourfile
```

The output:

```
2017061505,482.46MB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061505,
2017061505,722.58MB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061506,
2017061507,1054.72MB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061507,
2017061507,1280MB,hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/diameter__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017061508,
```

---

Note, the nominal unit value in informatics is **1024**

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution in awk:

```
awk '$2 ~ /[0-9\.]+GB/ { $2 = int($2 * 1024) "MB" } 1' FS="," OFS="," table.txt
```

Feel free to add another rule for kB conversion (just divide by 1024).